# Subscribing to PropertyChanged on current item in ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm

Is it bad practice to subsribe to PropertyChanged event of the currently selected entity. Lets say that I have a grid that is bound to List and I have binded Grid's SelectedItem to ViewModel's SelectedItem property.

```
private Customer _selectedItem;
public Customer SelectedItem
{
    get {return _selectedItem;}
    set
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_selectedItem, value))
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(()=>SeletedItem);
            _selectedItem.PropertyChanged += OnCustomerPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Does this code has any drawbacks, performance wise, memory-leak wise, or it is safe to use it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are leaking event subscriptions.  There is nothing wrong with the idea of binding to SelectedItem, but you need to remember to unsubscribe later.  You also should be null-checking your value before subscribing and unsubscribing:

```
private Customer _selectedItem;
public Customer SelectedItem
{
    get {return _selectedItem;}
    set
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_selectedItem, value))
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(null, _selectedItem))
                _selectedItem.PropertyChanged -= OnCustomerPropertyChanged;
            _selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(()=>SelectedItem);
            if (!ReferenceEquals(null, _selectedItem))
                _selectedItem.PropertyChanged += OnCustomerPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, as you go through selecting item after item, *all* of your previously selected items will have their PropertyChanged event handlers hooked to `OnCustomerPropertyChanged`.  That in turn could lead to memory leaks (because event handlers can prevent the event-raising object from being GC'd) or unexpected behavior.